# How many 3 dimensional lattices are possible mathematically?

Tags: 3d, solid-geometry, chemistry

Recently I was studying solid chemistry (crystal lattices) and there was a line in my text book.

> A French mathematician, Bravais, showed that there are only 14 possible three-dimensional lattices. These are called **Bravais lattices.**

So what got me intrigued was if this constraint on number of lattices a mathematical or a chemical one?

I think it is mathematically possible to create infinite lattices but I am not sure.

Question :

What limits the number of lattices in three dimensions?

Comment: I am not sure if this question is more suitable for chemistry stackexchange

Comment: It is more appropriate here.  The limit is geometrical and has nothing to do with atoms.  You could see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravais_lattice)  It shows pictures of each.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are infinitely many lattices in the mathematical sense(discrete subgroups of full dimension), but only finitely many possible symmetry groups of such lattices. The limits mainly come from the fact that rotational symmetry is only possible with very few rotational angles

Comment: Can someone provide a proof in a answer?